# Sending mails and narrowing what script does it

Tags: linux, php, postfix, sendmail, mta

I'm using a very old Ubuntu server that was some time ago a mail server which was infected. Sadly there is a running web page on that server. Some script/page/malware is trying to send a lot of spam - I know because /var/spool/postfix/maildrop is filling quite quickly.

I was thinking that changing php5/cli/php.ini sendmail_path to something not valid will stop this. Sadly it doesn't (I've reloaded Apache). The server is so old that even iotop ain't working. (need kernel + packages upgrade, which ain't going to happen).

Is there any way to narrow the main problem here? Is there a way to check which file is trying to send spam so I can delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it is not your mail server which is infected.  You may have a spambot running on the server and sending email directly.  If the spam is not recorded in your email logs, then this is likely the case.

The following IP tables rules will block spambots and programs running as other userids from sending email.

```
iptables -A OUTPUT --dport 25 -m owner --uid-owner XX -j ACCEPT  # Where XX is the UID of the Email server
iptables -A OUTPUT --dport 25 -j LOG  --log-level 6 --log-prefix "Outgoing SMTP blocked:"
iptables -S OUTPUT --dport 25 -j DROP
```

You may want to run a netstat command as root a few times to see which programs are sending messages.  I would use a command something like:

```
netstat -antp | grep :25
```

It is important to keep your distribution up to date.  Using LTS you can do a version upgrade every 2 years, and the normal release cycle is every 6 months.  A package like `unattended-upgrades` can apply updates as they become available.

Comment: the only process that use :25 is apache2

Comment: I added iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j DROP and INPUT chain same. netstat is not clean, still I can't find the file thats try to send those mails. From -j LOG i see that my server is trying to connect to other servers on port 25. I would like to get the file that is doing this

Comment: @MichalSapsa apache2 should not be connecting to :25 unless it is connecting to a mail relay.  Usually it would be localhost (127.0.0.1:25), but it could be configured for another host.  It is possible someone dropped a script in one of the webserver's directories which is being used to send the spam.  If you can, shut the web server down until you locate it.  The log entries should indicate you are now blocking the spambot, but it still needs to be identified and removed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to help of @BillThor - big thanks, and few similar question here at superuser I manage to do this:

1) Disable input and output of port 25 (smtp)

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j LOG  --log-level 6 --log-prefix "SMTP BLOCK:"
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j DROP
```

2) Disable any imap/courier/pop/smtp service at server (it was old mail server, now it's not so no point of having those)

3) I download [maldetect](https://www.rfxn.com/projects/linux-malware-detect/) which instantly showed me problematic files like img23141243.php.jpg or img1321312.php.gif

After cleaning this old web server account there is no apache2 connecting on :25 anywere.
Been monitoring this with help of loging any outgoing activite on port 25, and with

```
netstat -antp | grep :25
```

4) sadly LMD didn't found every malware on server, but I used the [HowToForge Article](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-log-emails-sent-with-phps-mail-function-to-detect-form-spam) about how to redirect sendmail command to external script that will log every attempt for sending mails, which log path to folder of infected file. thanks to that i found sql.php which was infected.